# Problems while saving events using Syncfusion

Tags: asp.net-core, scheduler, datetimepicker, syncfusion

So recently I started working with Syncfusion Scheduler and I noticed that everytime I click save, the components are probably re-rendered and reset their values. For example when I choose date and time from one of the datepickers, change event is prompted and I get the new value, but then when I click save, the value changes once again to the current time and date.

Can I stop it somehow? The save button should let me read the values from components as they are, not rerender them.

```
function onPopupOpen(args) {
            if (args.type === 'Editor') {
                var eventData = args.data;

                var startElement = args.element.querySelector('#StartTime');
                var startDrop = startElement.classList.item(3);

                var startPicker = startElement.ej2_instances[0];
                startPicker.change = function () {
                    eventData.StartTime = startPicker.value;
                };

                var processElement = args.element.querySelector('#TrainerId');

                var dropdown = document.getElementById("TrainerId").ej2_instances[0];
                dropdown.previousItemData = null;
                var saveButton = args.element.querySelector('.e-event-save');

                saveButton.onclick = function () {
                    console.log('save clicked');
                    eventData.StartTime = startPicker.value;

                    if (!dropdown.previousItemData) {
                        console.log('Choose a trainer');
                    } else {
                        eventData.TrainerId = dropdown.previousItemData.Id;

                    }

                };

            }
        }
```

The trainer dropdown came with similar issue, but I 'fixed' it by looking at the previous item.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the e-field class for the Start and end time input, there is no need to bind the change event for datepickers. It allows the processing of those field values internally. Refer the below shared documentation.

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/schedule/editor-template?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#customizing-event-editor-using-template

```
<script id="EventEditorTemplate" type="text/template">
<table class="custom-event-editor" width="100%" cellpadding="5">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="e-textlabel">Summary</td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <input id="Subject" class="e-field e-input" type="text" value="" name="Subject" style="width: 100%" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="e-textlabel">Status</td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <input type="text" id="EventType" name="EventType" class="e-field" style="width: 100%" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="e-textlabel">From</td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <input id="StartTime" class="e-field" type="text" name="StartTime" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="e-textlabel">To</td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <input id="EndTime" class="e-field" type="text" name="EndTime" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="e-textlabel">Reason</td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <textarea id="Description" class="e-field e-input" name="Description" rows="3" cols="50" style="width: 100%; height: 60px !important; resize: vertical"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onPopupOpen(args) {
    if (args.type === 'Editor') {
        var statusElement = args.element.querySelector('#EventType');
        if (!statusElement.classList.contains('e-dropdownlist')) {
            var dropDownListObject = new ej.dropdowns.DropDownList({
                placeholder: 'Choose status', value: statusElement.value,
                dataSource: ['New', 'Requested', 'Confirmed']
            });
            dropDownListObject.appendTo(statusElement);
            statusElement.setAttribute('name', 'EventType');
        }
        var startElement = args.element.querySelector('#StartTime');
        if (!startElement.classList.contains('e-datetimepicker')) {
            new ej.calendars.DateTimePicker({ value: new Date(startElement.value) || new Date() }, startElement);
        }
        var endElement = args.element.querySelector('#EndTime');
        if (!endElement.classList.contains('e-datetimepicker')) {
            new ej.calendars.DateTimePicker({ value: new Date(endElement.value) || new Date() }, endElement);
        }
    }
}
```

Refer to the below shared UG documentation to know more about how to save customized editor template.

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/schedule/editor-template?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=razor#how-to-save-the-customized-event-editor-using-template